# linkings several docker containers together

Tags: selenium, hyperlink, rabbitmq, containers, docker

My current docker images

```
tutum/rabbitmq                          latest              2b111aa3d5e9        3 days ago          379.1 MB
stackbrew/ubuntu                        12.04               74fe38d11401        2 weeks ago         209.6 MB
ubuntu                                  trusty              99ec81b80c55        2 weeks ago         266 MB
damm/java8                              latest              2fea811f78ac        7 weeks ago         759.5 MB
aglover/java8                           latest              931742e1ae7d        7 weeks ago         1.186 GB
vvoyer/docker-selenium-firefox-chrome   latest              61b0381789d1        5 months ago        1.087 GB
```

I started the selenium-firefox-chrome container by running

```
  docker run -p 4444:4444 -p 5999:5999 -d vvoyer/docker-selenium-firefox-chrome
```

To this container, I wanted to link, damm/java8, and tutum/rabbitmq, I was having trouble with the command to link them.

mycont = my running selenium-firefox-chrome container

So far I have tried something along the following

```
docker run -d --link mycont:db damm/java8
```

How do I properly link damm/java8 and tutum/rabbitmq? not sure if I am using the correct commands

Comment: What do you want to do with the linked containers? What environment variables do you see in the `damm/java8` container? You should see `DB_PORT` (since you aliased `mycont` to `db`). Those `DB_PORT` variables should be what you use to connect to the linked container (mycont) from `damm/java8`

Comment: It is important to note that you can only link to containers that are already running, so you can never have every container linked to every container.